# buttons are not disabling on callback function "beforeshow" of datepicker. 

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to disable all the buttons on the page when callback function "beforeShow" is executed. But this is not happening. Am I missing something?? Or do I need to add something more?

My Code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){  
    var inputs = $("#containigdiv").find("input[type='button']");           
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,                               
        beforeShow: function(){                     
            inputs.attr('disabled','disabled');
        },                
        onClose: function(dateText) {                       
            inputs.attr('disabled','');
        }
    });
});
```

Now I'm able to disable buttons but still the disabled button gets focus when I try choose the day on the calender which falls on this button and hence day is not chosen.

Comment: Could you check whether `inputs` is empty or not?

Comment: I checked it. It is not empty but showing reference of both the buttons which I have on the page. [Object Object]